# window.open in background.js in firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am converting a working chrome extension to a firefox extension. In the extension, it calls window.open() in the background.js. However, it is not working in my firefox version, and I have tested that everything else is working fine, and it is just not window.open'ing.

I read online that it could be due to a security issue? How do I adjust the security settings so it will be able to run, and how do I notify the user to?

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Instagram Liker",
"description": "Instagram Liker",
"version": "1",
"icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/custom.js"
        ]
    }
],
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "js/background.js"
    ]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

}

The window.open is just being called in a function in the background.js, I don't think I need to post that code.

Comment: Could you please post some example code? One thing that may be causing the issue is the manifest file. What version of Firefox are you using? Make sure you understand the API reference too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension

Comment: @alex i will post the code rn

Answer (score 3):

I encounter exactly the same problem, solution is to not use

```
window.open("yourUrl")
```

but instead use method provided only for browser extensions

```
browser.windows.create({url: ""yourUrl""});
```

With this solution you can be sure your event page won't be blocked by any popup blocker.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me without the double "":
`browser.windows.create({url: yourUrl});`

Answer (score 0):

More than likely popup blocker is blocking the window from opening, make sure you allow pop-up windows in the permissions of the website you are trying to call `window.open()` on.